# Where to place configuration settings for Web API

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, connection-string, app-config

I am using Web API and entity framework. Initially my connection string is in web.config file. Web API is hosted in IIS Server.  Connection string will be encrypted by utility(executable not known may be third party) so when connection string will encrypt in web.config then API will restart again and we don't want to restart the API.

Can I keep all my settings in app.config instead of web.config to avoid restart of web API or registry is a good choice to keep connection string over config files?

I have used below code read connection string from app.config.

```
string codeBase = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        string configPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "database.config");

        if (File.Exists(configPath))
        {
            var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
            {
                ExeConfigFilename = configPath
            };

            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            string connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseContext"].ToString();

        }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: you can have the connection string in app.config file but you have to treat it like a file , System.configuration will not going to pick it in a web application. and as far as restart, IIS app pool anyways restarts every 29 hours by default until unless you have changed that value.

Comment: As @Prashant has mentioned above, you can't store it in app.config. Another approach which I can think of is to store the encrypted connection strings in flat file or database and read and decrypt them in server side.

Comment: @Prashant, I have shared code above to read connection string from app.config. If i change connection string at run time (encrypt the connection string ) then Will it restart App pool of web API ? Please confirm or should i move it to database